# getting empty arrays when making a get request using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, axios

Hi :) I'm trying to get an array of numbers from my api that returns me something like: `[{"numbers":[9,7,56,58,48,18],"gameId":1},{"numbers":[3,8,10,60,35,5],"gameId":2},{"numbers":[39,24,33,26,48,55],`

I'm using axios and everytime I make a request this is what happens: `[] length: 0 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

this is my code:

```
const[game,setGame]= React.useState([]);
var[myGameNumbers, setMyGameNumbers]=React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/games/game12").then((response)=>{
     setGame(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  if (!game) return null;

function mappingNumbers(){
    game.map((game) => (
        setMyGameNumbers==game
    ));
    if(!myGameNumbers) return null; else console.log(myGameNumbers);
}
```

this is the button that triggers the function:

```
 <a href="#" className="button" onClick={mappingNumbers()}>
     <p className="bttn-p">GERAR NÚMEROS</p>
 </a>
```

I'm looking for a way to bring my array numbers, like this: `[9,7,56,58,48,18]` everytime I click on the button. If anyone knows how to help I'd be thankful :D

this is my full code if theres anything I've left out: https://github.com/vitoriaacarvalho/jogando-na-mega-sena/tree/main/front/jogando-na-mega

Comment: What is the output of the `response` after the get?

Comment: @FabrícioPinto the console only returns [] length: 0 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: Maybe its a problem with your API, on your browser press F12 to open the dev tools, go to the Network tab, click on your button and see if your request appears on the list, if so click on it and confirm if the URL is correct, the headers and if the response has the JSON that you expected.

Comment: Probably not solving your issue but, your `onClick` should either be `() => mappingNumbers()` or `mappingNumbers` currently it will invoke immediately

Comment: @FabrícioPinto I tried this and apparently my back works fine! I believe my front logic is wrong :(

Comment: @RubenSmn It didn't really solve it but thank you! I didn't know the sintax was wrong <3

Comment: @vitoriac when you say "the console only returns [] length: 0 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)" is that from the console in the `mappingNumbers`?

Comment: @RubenSmn yess!! I only put it there for testing, before I was only trying to return the data to display on the screen but nothing happened!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `mappingNumbers` you map over the `game` and do some check `==` against the `setMyGameNumbers` function which will not work. The correct syntax will be something like `setMyGameNumbers(game)`

You also check if `myGameNumbers` does not exist but it will always exist since the initial value is an empty array `[]` this is why the **console.log** logs an empty array.

```js
...

if (!game) return null;

// will log everytime when a state gets updated
// and if the above statement is false
console.log("myGameNumbers", myGameNumbers);

function mappingNumbers() {
  if (game.length < 1) return null;
  setMyGameNumbers(game);
}
```

Updated the `onClick` with a correct syntax

```js
<a href="#" className="button" onClick={() => mappingNumbers()}>
  <p className="bttn-p">GERAR NÚMEROS</p>
</a>
```